# Binance websocket sending duplicate data

Tags: python, api, websocket, binance

This is my code to get futures tick data. It seems to be working but on some ticks, I am receiving the same data again.

```
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client
from binance import BinanceSocketManager
import asyncio

api_key ='***'
api_secret ='***'

#Individual Futures Socket
client1 = Client(api_key=api_key,api_secret=api_secret)
bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client1)
socket = bsm.individual_symbol_ticker_futures_socket(symbol='ETHUSDT')

#Convert to dataframe
def createframe(msg):
    df = pd.DataFrame([msg['data']])
    df = df.loc[:, ['s', 'E', 'c']]
    df.columns = ['symbol', 'Time', 'Price']
    df.Price = df.Price.astype(float)
    df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, unit='ms')
    return df

async def main():
    while True:
        await socket.__aenter__()
        msg = await socket.recv()
        frame = createframe(msg)
        print(frame)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Getting following output:

```
    symbol                    Time    Price
0  ETHUSDT 2021-08-09 08:50:19.574  2960.49
    symbol                    Time    Price
0  ETHUSDT 2021-08-09 08:50:20.060  2960.33
    symbol                    Time    Price
0  ETHUSDT 2021-08-09 08:50:20.060  2960.33
```

The last two outputs are the same. Is there a way to avoid this as I am going to save the dataframe to a sqlite database and dont want repeating rows.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
async def main():
async with bsm.individual_symbol_ticker_futures_socket(symbol='ETHUSDT') as socket:
    while True:
        msg = await socket.recv()
        frame = createframe(msg)
        print(frame)

if __name__ == "__main__":
await main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Not sure if it is relevant to you now, but here was my solution.

I found out that if I comment out the line with `await socket.__aenter__()` I would not receive the duplicate values, and from tests, this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

BinanceSocketManager requires asyncio programming:

Try below:

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient



async def main():
    client1 = await AsyncClient.create()
    bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client1)

    socket = bsm.individual_symbol_ticker_futures_socket(symbol='ETHUSDT')

    async with socket as tscm:

    while True:
        msg = await tscm.recv()
        frame = createframe(msg)
        print(frame)

    await client.close_connection()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    await main()
```